# How to display locally stored HTML pages in ios app with style sheet

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I am working on ios app that uses html is pages on about screen. All files are locally sotred. I can open those files in an app but only problem is with style sheets. Somehow they are not applied .html files. Does anyone know how to tackle this issue ? 
For URL generation I am using following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResources:@"html_file_name" withExtension:@"html"];
```

Comment: try them on a pc and see if the external css are applied

Comment: Yes, If I open them directly in finder it does work.

Comment: I would suspect it's a path issue

Comment: just added code that I am using for URL generation...

Comment: I meant the external css file you included in your HTML file, has a path issue, not your HTML file. Looking at your code above I'm more confident that you css file has a path issue. For simple, try to put the css file within the same folder with your generated HTML file and modify the link in that HTML file accordingly and test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also use HTML, in my case for help texts.  Because the styling is very limited, which might also be in your case, I did this:

```
NSString* htmlTop    = @"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><style>body{font-family:'Helvetica';font-size:14px</style><body>";
NSString* htmlBottom = @"</body></html>";

helpText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", htmlTop, helpText, htmlBottom];

self.webView.dataDetectorTypes           = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
self.webView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;

[self.webView loadHTMLString:helpText baseURL:nil];
```

I have the individual help texts as unstyled HTML in a JSON array, which explains why I also place some HTML at top and bottom; so I don't repeat that in each text.

Note: Without `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal` the webview's scrolling is sluggish, and different from other iOS UI elements, like tables.